# How to find average distance which needs to be traveled to find a car accident using poisson distribution?

Tags: statistics

I have a textbook (D&D Resource Ltd Practice External Assessments 3) question which is confusing me quite a bit.

"Studies show that there is an average of 0.2 breakdown on each one kilometre of the Wellington motorway on any particular day.

If a towing service wants to be available to tow a vehicle that has broken down, what length of the motorway would they have to patrol to have a probability of 0.75 of being close to at least one breakdown?"

So I understand that you go (1-0.75) to get 0.25, so you plug in probability 0.25 and X=0 into the Poisson distribution formula which gives you a mean of 1.3863.

Firstly, what is exactly does this mean value mean? Is it the average number of breakdowns over a distance?

A secondly, the answer scheme says that in order to find the answer to this question, you go 1.3863 divided by 0.2. This is the bit I'm struggling to get my head around. Why does dividing the average in the Poisson distribution by the average number of breakdown over 1km give you the length of road which needs to be traveled in order to come across a crash?

And just a follow up, would the mean in the Poisson distribution when the probability is 0.25 and x is zero be the same as when the probability is 0.75 and the x is equal of greater than 1?